# How to assign an associative array to another variable in zsh?

Tags: arrays, shell, associative-array, zsh

In zsh, is there a way to assign an associative array to another variable? I would like to to something like this:

```
typeset -A orig
orig=(key1 val1 key2 val2)
typeset -A other
other=$orig
print '$orig:  '$orig
print '$other: '$other
print '$orig[key1]: '$orig[key1]
print '$other[key1]: '$other[key1]
```

This will print:

```
$orig:  val1 val2
$other: val1 val2
$orig[key1]: val1
$other[key1]:
```

I want to be able to use `$other[key1]` and get `val1`.

I know I can iterate over the keys and copy it item by item, but I really want to avoid this. Also, `eval` is evil :)

I have tried `other=($orig)` and other variations, but this will get my values from `orig` and create as associative array like this

```
other=(val1 val2)
```

So `other[key1]` returns nothing and `other[val1]` returns `val2`, which is not what I want.

If I understand correctly, what is going on in every attempt of mine is that `$other` is getting an array of the *values* of `$orig`, without the keys. How can I make it receive both keys **and** values and have the correct association between them?

I'm not worried about null values, if that would even be a problem,
because I am sure `$orig` will be well behaved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to delve into the wonderful world of parameter expansion flags :) The `k` and `v` flags can be used together to force an associative array to expand to both its keys and values.

```
$ typeset -A orig
$ orig=(key1 val1 key2 val2)
$ print ${(kv)orig}
key1 val1 key2 val2
```

Then you can use the `set` command to populate your copy with the alternating key/values produced by that expansion.

```
$ typeset -A other
$ set -A other ${(kv)orig}
$ print $other[key1]
val1
```

These and other flags are documented in `man zshexpn` under "Parameter Expansion Flags", which is one of my favorite `zsh` features.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! The only thing I don't understand is why is the `set -A` needed. I tried without it and it worked. Also, sorry for not upvoting you, I tried but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: The example I found used `set -A`, but I think it's just an alternative to `other=( ${(kv)orig} )`.

Comment: Can you make it work with positional parameters in place of 'other' and 'orig'?

Comment: Nice one but what if some keys have no value, e.g. `orig[key1]=;` ?

Comment: @cpm Combine that with "regular" parameter expansion; `"${(kv)orig[@]}"` would expand to `key1` and `''` (the empty string).

Comment: The `typeset` and `set` can be combined into one statement like `typeset -A other=( ${(kv)orig} )`. (And I actually prefer `declare` over `typeset` but that’s personal taste.)

Answer (score 5):

`zsh: bad set of key/value pairs for associative array`

Perfect world without escaping:

```
$ typeset -A old new
$ old=(k1 v1 k2 v2 k3 v3)
$ typeset old    # old=( k1 v1 k2 v2 k3 v3 )
```

...doesn't exist and your arrays usually include empty values:

```
$ old[k2]=
$ typeset old    # old=( k1 v1 k2 '' k3 v3 )
```

...therefore you need to use `"` (quoting), `@` (escaping) and `f` (field separation):

```
$ typeset new    # new=( )
$ new=("${(@fkv)old}")
$ typeset new    # new=( k1 v1 k2 '' k3 v3 )
```

See `man zshexpn` for more on parameter expansion flags.